# Why slick slider swipe slides forward, and backward?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a slider

```
<div class="my-projects-slider" id="js-my-projects-slider">
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/5.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/6.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/8.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/9.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/5.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="my-projects-slider__item"><img src="assets/i/projects/6.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

And the js code

```
$('#js-my-projects-slider').slick({
dots: false,
slidesToShow: 8,
slidesToScroll: 2,
arrows: true,
responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 7
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 1400,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 6
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 1200,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 5
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 1000,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 700,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 500,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3,
      arrows: false
    }
  }
]
```

});

I mean to scroll just 2 slides when i click arrow. 
But when i press first time is swipe 2 slides forward, second time - 2 slides forward, and when i click 3 time - swipe some slides backward.

What is the reason?

This is the site [enter link description here]my-site[1](http://portfolio.webforworld.info/)
The slider under the russia map

Thansk

Comment: probably because you run out of slides and go back to initial slide

Comment: It works as it is, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4d197yq/).

Comment: What you mean, out of slides?

Comment: And what i must see it the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I understand whats happend.

I have 13 slides and scrolling by 2. This is the reason.
I change slides to 14 and it works.